# using selenium to attach a file to a file field made by knockout.js

Tags: ruby, selenium, knockout.js, capybara

Normally, attaching a file is relatively straight forward

If I have an element that looks like this;

```
<input 
id="DataFile_123" 
type="file">
```

I can write this

```
find(:xpath, 'input[@id="Data_123"]').send_keys('c:\file_dir\file.txt')
```

With knockout.js I'm seeing file types like so...

```
<input 
type="file" 
data-bind="value: fileName, 
event: { change: handleFileChange }" 
accept=".csv">
```

I found an abstract of the exact type of file from AlexZeitler  http://jsfiddle.net/AlexZeitler/fPWFd/

trying to find this input creates the same errors as below

When I go after something like this with similar selenium code I'm blocked

```
 find(:xpath, 'input[@type="file"]').send_keys('c:\file_dir\file.txt')  #ElementNotFound
```

The syntactic sugar around the script to execute throws me.

```
execute_script('handleFileChange.js') # returns handleFileChange is not defined
```

Has someone had good luck attaching files in knockout?  Let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. The format of the 2nd `input` is not the same as the first one but you stated that you used the same Selenium code. Your posted code is referencing an id that doesn't exist in the 2nd case. Maybe post the code you are using against the 2nd `input` would help?

Comment: Good point JeffC,  the second find statement is not the same, it is written to catch the knockout input. I edited my question.

Comment: I would start with this... open the dev console in Chrome and navigate to the page. Type `$x('input[@type="file"]').length` in the console and make sure it returns 1. If it doesn't, it's likely that the first `input` on the page is in a hidden area and you will have to find a more specific locator.

Comment: If there is only 1 `input` on the page, it's possible that you will have to wait for that element to be visible before interacting with it.

Comment: OK. Then there's something wrong with the XPath. Is the element inside an iframe?

Comment: I link to the page would help a lot also.

Comment: `execute_script` take the text of the JS to run in page context, it doesn't take a JS file to load and run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very often file input fields are hidden to allow for better styling.  There are many ways to hide the field and without seeing the CSS being applied it's impossible to give a 100% sure way to fix this, however if you're using the latest version of Capybara and there is only one file input on the page you can try

```
attach_file('c:\file_dir\file.txt', make_visible: true)
```

That will attempt to find the non-visible file element, modify the elements CSS to make it visible, attach the file, and then revert the CSS to what it was.  If there is more than one file input element on the page you can still use it by scoping to a visible area of the page that only contains one.

Comment: got back ```Unable to find file field nil (Capybara::ElementNotFound)```

Comment: @TangibleDream Then you're not on the page you think you are or you  don't have a file field on the page - check your `page.html` source

Comment: I found an abstract of my issue so you can see what I'm talking about. Check the link http://jsfiddle.net/AlexZeitler/fPWFd/

Comment: @TangibleDream in that case the file input is inside an iframe - is it in an iframe in your case?

Comment: checked for that, no

Comment: Then you're going to need to post your HTML (`page.html`) somewhere, because it works fine with the example you posted - https://gist.github.com/twalpole/144845468ec8090497f2496cae480bb3 - If it's telling you it can't find the file input element, it's not on your page (or it's in an iframe which you'd need to switch into like in the example page)

Comment: Arrgh you are right!,  got it to work with the new attach file!